# Why can I see files with .aspx extension, but not files with .aspx.cs in my project directory?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Why I see files with `.aspx` extension, but not files with `.aspx.cs` in my project directory? I know if I want to see the file with `.aspx.cs` file I need to right click view code. Where are they stored?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. If you are referring to not being able to see them in 'Solution Explorer' then you can click on "Show All Files" in solution explorer.

Comment: I am sorry. I used the wrong tag. I was referring to asp.net webforms. I apologize for the mistake. I will edit my question. Thanks for the reply though.